# How to make SOAP types not force lowercase after migrating from CF10 to CF2016?

Tags: soap, coldfusion

We are in the process of migrating from the latest update on CF10 to the latest update on CF2016. An issue we are running into is that for the webservices we publish, when we previously specified returntype as components the WSDL and response XML preserved the camel-casing. After migrating all of the complex return types are lower case. The change was so minor we didn't even notice it in testing but it is apparently causing some users problems with code written for the original casing.

I have search around and can not find a mention of a change forcing everything to lowercase but that appears to be what is happening. We are still on Windows Server, going from 2008 to 2012, so no change in OS that might warrant this.

Does anyone know when this change went into effect and/or how to tweak settings to preserve casing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that the Mapping in Server Settings is what is causing this difference. Actually behaves the same way on CF10 and CF2016.

If a mapping is setup for the webservices application root file path...

1. the mapping's logical path is use to create a namespace for the webservice
2. camel casing or some honoring of casing is done (seems inconsistent)

Without a mapping for the webservices app base path, the namespace is just a default and all cfc names in complex types are lower case.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and documenting what you found.